# Finding TagNames from multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to complete a find and replace function through to a word document using a sheet with many separate tables of data. Is it possible to refer to different rows of `TagName` to return the `TagValue` in the row immediately underneath?

The code below is able to achieve this in a row 7. But my next table of data begins in row 15. I'm hoping there is an easier option than repeating this code for every table.

```
For CustCol = 5 To 14

    TagName = .Cells(7, CustCol).Value
    TagValue = .Cells(8, CustCol).Value

    With WordDoc.Content.Find
        .Text = TagName
        .Replacement.Text = TagValue
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With

Next CustCol
```

Any help or input would be appreciated!

Comment: It's not quite clear how these "tag rows" can be identified. Do you know that they'll always be the same row numbers? So you could put these numbers in an array then loop the array?

Comment: Yes tag rows will always be the same rows. All tags have a <<...>> format, but I can't find a way to search for this. I'll have a go using looped array, thanks.